# URL Rewrite not working on directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to set up a URL Rewrite for my website, hosted on 1&1.

Here is my .htaccess on root directory ( ./ )

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .html .htm
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^404$ /404.html [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404

RewriteRule ^login$ /login.html [L]
RewriteRule ^register$ /register.html [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.html [L]

RewriteRule ^admin$ /admin.html [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/user$ /administration/user.html [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/user/p/([0-9]+)$ /administration/user.html?p=$1 [L]
```

There is something strange with it :

- if I go to website.com/login it works well (/login.html)
- if I go to website.com/admin it works well (/admin.html)
- if I go to website.com/admin/user it goes to /admin.html instead of /administration/user.html (like if I
  tried website.com/admin)

Even if I change the order or if I delete the line `RewriteRule ^admin$ /admin.html [L]` and I try to go to website.com/admin or website.com/admin/user I still have the same page (/admin.html) like if the url rewrite was in cache or something.

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: `administration/user.html` assumes there is a real directory `administration/`. Does that directory have its own .htaccess file inside? Does it contain any rewrite rules?

Comment: Yes indeed there is a administration directory, with no .htaccess inside

Comment: When you say _it goes to /admin.html_ do you mean to say it actually does a 301 or 301 _redirect_ to `/admin.html` instead of an internal rewrite?

Comment: The url is /admin/user but the content of the page is /admin.html (instead of /administration/user.html)

Comment: Browser caching can be confusing when testing rewrites; did you try this in another browser? There really doesn't appear to be anything wrong with what you have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to enabling of `MultiViews` on your Apache host. Disable it by using this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.